# Поиск без учета регистра python + django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте. Поиск по сайту работает только с учетом регистра. Как можно исправить? 
Код поиска:

```
class SearchResultsView(ArticlesView):

def get_queryset(self, request):
    if request.POST.has_key('search'):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=request.POST['search']) |
            Q(content__icontains=request.POST['search'])
            ).distinct()
    return []

def post(self, request):
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset(request)
    context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: В доках есть такой способ Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains='Lennon')

Comment: странно почему `icontains` не работает как ожидалось но скажу точно, что в поиске не нужно использовать `POST` запрос, используйте `GET`, первый нужен только когда хотите изменить данные в базе.

Comment: А база у вас какая? Вообще ваш код должен работать.

Answer (score 2):

`строка.lower()` - убирает регистр `строка.upper()` делает буквы заглавными. Это можно применить в фильтре при определинии (названия например), а затем уже сравнить без регистра.

Comment: А разве icontains в отличие от contains не должен искать без учета регистра?

Comment: @Coveraver, я написал простой и универсальный способ, работает и без django, например при поиске файлов без учёта регистра

Comment: icontains всего лишь делает обычный LIKE, который тоже от django не зависит. Зависит только от поддержки бд, поэтому LIKE там на каждую бд разный. Ваше решение - костыль

Answer (score 0):

```
Q(title__iregex=request.POST['search'])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

благодарю, ибо по совершенно непонятной мне причине(как любителю php), но lower и upper в django не работают в этом случае. Как оказалось, заглавные буквы после upper это не тоже самое, что и заглавные в базе... для lower аналогичный ПАРАДОКС. Потом ещё более странное стечение обстоятельств, конструкция с

> <strike>Q(title__icontains=q)</strike>

сначала работала, а потом тоже перестала(вообще странно-плавающая ошибка, жди от куда прилетит...), и только этот способ

> Q(title__iregex=q)

сейчас решил мой вопрос, надеюсь это уже не изменится.... А использовать должно быть понятно как, кто задаётся подобными вопросами... Например, так:

```
search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if search_form.is_valid():
    q = search_form.cleaned_data['q']
    products = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(title__iregex=q) | Q(title__iregex=q)
    )
```